# Join function not working in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**Code:**

```
$file=file(example);
$arr[]=$file[0];
$arr[] .="interactions. Sage Publications.";

echo count($arr);  //outputs 2
echo $arr[0];  //outputs   Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting
echo $arr[1];  //outputs   interactions. Sage Publications

$str=join(" ",$arr);
//outputs
Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting
interactions. Sage Publications
```

**Issue:** Though I use join function the two arrays are not joined in the output. Am getting the output in two lines. I want it in a single line.

**Alternative code:**

```
$arrp =array("Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting","interactions. Sage Publications.");
$str= join(" ",$arrp);
echo $str; //outputs Multiple Regression: Testing and Interpreting interactions. Sage Publications
```

If I parse the array value directly into the variable am getting the desired output(i.e.output in a single line).What's the wrong in my previous code.Are both code not same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your `file(..)` returns an array of line that contains the ending newline character. Your file actually looks like:

```
lines[0] = "first line\n";
lines[1] = "second line";
```

.. so that when you `join(..)` it, the string has two lines.

---

Solution #1:

```
$trimmedLines = file('yourFile', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Solution #2:

```
$TrimmedLine = rtrim($arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_merge — Merge one or more arrays

```
<?php


    $first_array = array('1', '2');
    $second_array = array('3', '4');
    $final_data = array_merge($first_array, $second_array);

    var_dump($final_data);
    // output will be
    // 1, 2, 3, 4
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why your using array for this .Why don't you just use

```
$file=file(example);
echo trim($file[0]) . "interactions. Sage Publications.";
```

Comment: Am writing output to a file using `file_put_contents` function. When I echo it in a browser am getting the desiret output. But in a file the output is in two lines.